# Google Cloud Media CDN- Edge Cache Origin Error - Method Not Found

Tags: media, google-cdn

In Media CDN- When I am trying create a Edge Cache Origin, then it's Showing Erorr
"(gcloud.edge-cache.origins.create) NOT_FOUND: Method not found"

[Error- Method not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o6jBD.png)

Is there any face this problem? I am looking for Solution from the expert

Thanks in Advance

I checked All Steps of Command First to last, Everything seems to good.